# Mac Default Alt-Tab Switcher places Cursor in Middle of Apps List (not left side / MRU)

Tags: macos, alt-tab

The task switcher is correctly placing the Most Recently Used apps on the left. But the cursor is in the middle. So it is necessary to hit arrow key a few times.

Apparently this behavior is not the norm: other users say the cursor defaults to the left side of the app list for them.

Any ideas what configuration may be the culprit and/or may be changed to correct the behavior to start the cursor on the left?

Thanks!

Comment: What apps are you using. It is LRU for me and cmd-tab always takes me to the previous app

Comment: I revised the question because i realized the MRU is on the left. The problem is with the cursor location being in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting `Key Repeat` to `Slow` (not Off!) and `Delay Until Repeat` to `Long` fixed this for me in Mac OS 12.4 Monterey

these are in `System Preferences` -> `Keyboard`

Comment: Sounds correct. The old `KeyRemap4Macbook` (now `Karabiner` ) also plays with the repeat rate in a similar manner. Since few people use either of those i'll award to you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the keyboard initial delay for repeat is too low, apparently due to glitch(es) in  KeyRemap4Macbook.

The very low delay means that the cursor travels all the way into the middle of the apps list in a jiffy - instead of remaining on the left of the list.